# Converting currencies within a table using data from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to covert the currencies within a table of sales which uses Substitute IDs of all the related tables (and places them within the relevant column, so: SubstituteItemKey within the Item table is equal to the ItemID within mainsales) and specifies the transaction values. 
The Snippet of code which fails is:

```
inner join [dbo].[Multiplier] on [dbo].[dimday].[Day] = [dbo].[Multiplier].[Day]
```

The problem with the results to this code is that it produces duplicate rows and the results are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplier probably holds conversion rates for several currencies. But you don't join the appropriate currency to a mainsales record, but all currencies. Thus you get multiple records instead of one per factsale.

Change

```
inner join Multiplier 
  on [dbo].[dimDay].[Day] = [dbo].[Multiplier].[Day]
```

to something like

```
inner join Multiplier 
    on  [dbo].[dimDay].[Day] = [dbo].[Multiplier].[Day]
    and [dbo].[mainsales].[Currency] = [dbo].[Multiplier].[Currency]
```

Comment: No, I don't follow. A mainsales record must refer to a currency somehow. Otherwise, how would you know what the amounts mean? The Multiplier table also contains the currency. So use both to join the records.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Your so-called `currency` column contains the currency symbol. Be aware that many currencies share the same symbol (often the dollar sign $), that can cause problems in the future when you introduce further currencies to your tables.